# Read/Write data to Console generated by exe from windows form application

Tags: c#, forms, console

I have a simple c# windowsform application which calls an exe .The exe inturn opens a console. Is it possible to read and write data to the CONSOLE generated by the exe. I want to send data from my windows forms application

Comment: Do you need to pass parameters to console ?

Comment: KcDod Yes . i need to pass parameters to console in 2 subsquent steps(one after the other) . I want to achieve this without user interaction. i.e Obtain parameters from the form and pass it to the console.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass arguments using `Process.startInfo()`. And obtaining parameters should be done according to your requirement (may be reading from textbox etc.)

```
        // Extracting parameter from form
        string para1=textbox1.Text;

        // State the program to be start; PATH is the path to program .exe
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(PATH);

        // Passing arguments :para1 extracted from textbox (string type) 
        startInfo.Arguments = para1 

        // Starting process
        Process exec= Process.Start(startInfo);

        // optionally waiting for execution
        exec.WaitForExit();
```

Also this can be done in single line as follows,

```
// Simply define program to execute and pass a and b parameters
Process.Start(PATH,para1);
```

Note : path is a string like `"program1.exe"` or full path to your program

Additionally : You are not LIMITED to one parameter

```
        // Extracting parameter from form
        string para1=textbox1.Text;
        string para2=textbox2.Text;

        Process.Start(PATH,para1+" "+para2); // Pass 2 parameters (using + string concat)
```

You can send many parameters simply separating them by spaces.. When you need to include space in parameter simply escape them using `'\'`

Comment: This is exactly what i tried.This works for the initial parameters. But the problem in exe is that , after passing the initial parameters to the exe , there is a need for the user to enter 2 others parameters in subsequent steps in console(once the process starts). I want to pass these parameters as well programatically without user interaction.

Comment: KcDOD - I completely understand your code. So Para1 is passed to program1.exe as per your code. What if the program1.exe requires further parameters which can ONLY BE PASSED AFTER PROCESS STARTS(there is a need for the user to enter 2 others parameters in subsequent steps in console).

Comment: May be you could pass them as arguments too. You can simply store them and use when they are needed. (ex :- C# console programs take command line arguments to an array ; args[] .. C also take argumetns as array).

Comment: @Arun E Also you are not limited to one parameter :) you can send many .. Simply you need to separate parameters with spaces

Comment: Yes , I agree. But the exe needs only 1 parameter initially.After the process starts, user will be prompted to enter further data. Here is where i want to prevent user interaction and enter these data in console programatically.

Comment: There's no such easy option available than passing it parameters. You can pass parameters and not use them till your user need input, may be you need to change the codes a bit.. But you might look in to this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16031967/how-to-provide-user-input-to-console-application-by-c-sharp-code .. mark the answer as correct or upvote if useful :)

Comment: Thanks for ur help, I am new to stackoverflow and dont have enough rights to upvote .:)

Comment: great +1 .. But is it possible to pass reversely.. I mean, while i call an exe from windows form i don't know how much time the exe will take to complete.. so if the exe has 10 modules to complete, then i need to intimate WF when each module complete. so that i can put a progress bar in my form which load one by one when each module complete.. is it possible.. thanks

Answer (score 1):

If your executable is creating the console by using a Process instance that runs 'cmd.exe' then you can redirect the input and output of the console by setting the [StartupInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.startinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) of the Process...

```
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
```

...then you can hook into an event the occurs when user enters console input...

```
p.OutputDataReceived += new .DataReceivedEventHandler(ConsoleOutputHandler);

void ConsoleOutputHandler(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs rec)
{
    // do something with the data
}
```

Comment: Phil Thank you. But I do not want the user to input data to console. I want to take values from my form application and pass it to the console.